# Delphi: custom button in custom title bar - à la Firefox/Opera main menu button

Tags: delphi, firefox, button, titlebar, custom-titlebar

I want to create 5 buttons in a title bar of a window using this way: http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/

Firefox has one button (the same for Opera):

**Not maximized window**

[image]

**Maximized window**

[image]

How to make such buttons for my purpose? Rounded/curved, with bevels, with/without an image, with/without a gradient. Are there similar components? Do I need to make it manually? If so, then how? If it's not a button then what is it? Is there an alternative for it?

Comment: Didn't exploring it the same way as you point in your prior [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8753939/744588) (using your tools of the trade) give some hint on it's implementation? Moreover, Firefox is open source, maybe it's worth delving into its source code.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of a component that draws on the glass at the top of your form, check out the  `TRibbon` control that comes with Delphi 2010 and above. The source code is included with Delphi. I'd bet that the button is simply an image with an alpha channel. The `TRibbon` code also draw controls like that on glass.

Comment: The same applies to `DevExpress VCL` and `TMS Component Pack` assuming availability of the source code.

Comment: That's why I mentioned `TRibbon`, since it is included with Delphi. The other components you have to pay for.

Comment: You are right, they are proprietary. Hopeffuly sharing/discussing general information (not the source code disclosure anyway) related to their `Application button` implementation doesn't infringe copyright laws. I believe many people here on SO can help.

Comment: Yeah, one of the reasons that I didn't write a more complete answer is that there are so many things needed to implement such a button it's hard to put it all in one answer.