# Window without client area in WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

On these screenshots we can see unordinary window frame in different applications:

- QIP logo on its login window frame (not client area) - http://postimage.org/image/2fdjg0h44/
- Buttons (back/next) and address field on the Windows 7 explorer window frame - http://postimage.org/image/2fdrpp7l0/
- In Google Chrome tabs take place on the window frame

In all these windows client area is resized or/and replaced. Of course, it works with Windows Aero theme only.

I want to resize and replace client area of my window or hide it at all if it is possible. (C/C++ and Win API). How can I do it?

Comment: Pretty tricky to get this right. Start here: http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673040/winapi-create-resizable-window-without-title-bar-but-with-minimize-maximize-clo/7677568#7677568 and probably other questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to resize the nonclient area of the form: [Controls and the Desktop Window Manager](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/01/23/controls-and-the-desktop-window-manager.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

That effect is accomplished using the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea function.