# Delphi resizable form completely remove caption bar

Tags: delphi, windows-10

I remove the title bar from a VCL form that still needs to be resizable by setting

```
borderStyle := bsNone;
```

and override createParams:

```
procedure TfrmMain.createParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_THICKFRAME;
end;
```

This works fine when the window is maximized but adds a small caption bar above the client area (in Windows 10/1903) when the window is in normal state. Using WS_SIZEBOX instead of WS_THICKFRAME doesn't change this.

When I omit the create params override the additional bar is gone but the form is no longer resizable.

I use Delphi 10.3.2 Enterprise.

Comment: Accepted answer in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7677568/3636228) actually points to two Delphi exampšles on how to achieve what you wish even tho the original question was asked for C++ aplication. I guess readin those articles might come in handy to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to remove the border completely but then tell Windows that the edges of the window are to be considered sizing borders.

To do this, set `BorderStyle` to `bsNone` and respond to the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm5 }

procedure TForm1.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  D: Integer;
  P: TPoint;
begin

  D := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);

  P := Self.ScreenToClient(Message.Pos);

  if P.Y < D then
  begin
    if P.X < D then
      Message.Result := HTTOPLEFT
    else if P.X > ClientWidth - D then
      Message.Result := HTTOPRIGHT
    else
      Message.Result := HTTOP;
  end
  else if P.Y > ClientHeight - D then
  begin
    if P.X < D then
      Message.Result := HTBOTTOMLEFT
    else if P.X > ClientWidth - D then
      Message.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
    else
      Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
  end
  else
  begin
    if P.X < D then
      Message.Result := HTLEFT
    else if P.X > ClientWidth - D then
      Message.Result := HTRIGHT
  end;

end;

end.
```

I'm not sure if this can be considered "best practices", however. Nor do I feel confident that there aren't any unwanted side effects, besides the obvious ones.

As always, you should be very careful when you do "unusual" things.