# How to draw a custom caption bar like the yahoo messenger 11

Tags: delphi, draw, caption, aero-glass

As you can see, Y! messenger 11 have used some techniques to draw a beautiful caption bar. Its window's like normal windows in the Win 7 but have a special caption. Is this a glass frame? How can i create one like this??

[image]

Comment: A lot of interesting resources at this related question that I asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822609/resources-for-windows-aero-glass-and-compositing-dwm

Comment: Yes, this techniques is called `drawing on glass`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best reference I know for this is a series of articles by renowned Delphi expert Chris Rolliston.

- [Setting up a custom title bar on Vista/Windows 7](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/)
- [Setting up a custom title bar – reprise](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/setting-up-a-custom-title-bar-reprise/)

Comment: Found these too. An awful lot of work for this purpose, although the code is available with the article.

Comment: There's a lot of work involved in supporting an XP/Win2003 compatible fallback mode. If I read the articles linked above correctly, Chris didn't fully implement that logic. For a sample that fully implements it, check out the VCL Ribbon source code, which does implement custom non-client painting both in DWM on mode on windows 7 , and DWM off mode, as well as on Windows XP.